# Assigning an input value to a column's value in SQL Server stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I am trying to write a stored procedure that will take a date as input.

If the date passed is `18-07-2019`, then data from `17-07-2019 06:00 am`  till `18-07-2019 06:00 am` should be fetched from the database.

In the below stored procedure, I am taking `Reportdate` (`datetime` datatype) as the input. But I am unable to assign it to the column which contains the time (`TimestampUTC` column) in the database table that I am querying.

So as per the below logic, data is shown automatically from yesterday to today '(21-07-2019 to 22-07-2019)` and doesn't change based on the date entered by the user.

Showing part of the stored procedure here:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetElectricityData]
    @Reportdate DATETIME
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;    

    WITH t AS
    (
        SELECT a.name, b.Data , a.UnitId, b.TimestampUTC
        FROM [10.87.233.57,1433].[EMMA].[dbo].MeterTags a 
        JOIN [10.87.233.57,1433].[EMMA].[dbo].[DataLog] b ON a.MeterTagId = b.MeterTagId
        WHERE b.MeterTagId IN (388, 184, 196, 194, 197)
        AND TimestampUTC BETWEEN DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, GETDATE() - 1), 0) + '06:00'
                             AND DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, GETDATE()), 0) + '06:00'
    GROUP BY 
        DATEADD(minute, DATEDIFF(minute, 0, TimestampUTC) / 15 * 15, 0),
        a.name, b.Data, a.UnitId, b.TimestampUTC
 )
```

Any suggestions will be hugely helpful.

Comment: You might want to think about making that parameter a `DATE` instead of a `DATETIME`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see that you are referencing GETDATE() in the WHERE clause (twice). Replace them with your @Reportdate variable as per below.

```
    CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetElectricityData]
        @Reportdate DATETIME
    AS
    BEGIN
        SET NOCOUNT ON;    

        WITH t AS
        (
            SELECT a.name, b.Data , a.UnitId, b.TimestampUTC
            FROM [10.87.233.57,1433].[EMMA].[dbo].MeterTags a 
            JOIN [10.87.233.57,1433].[EMMA].[dbo].[DataLog] b ON a.MeterTagId = b.MeterTagId
            WHERE b.MeterTagId IN (388, 184, 196, 194, 197)
            AND TimestampUTC BETWEEN DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, @Reportdate - 1), 0) + '06:00'
                                 AND DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, @Reportdate), 0) + '06:00'
        GROUP BY 
            DATEADD(minute, DATEDIFF(minute, 0, TimestampUTC) / 15 * 15, 0),
            a.name, b.Data, a.UnitId, b.TimestampUTC
     )
```

Comment: no problem, feel free to mark this as the correct answer if it helped you to make it work as it was the original answer to your question and others were posted after this, thanks

Comment: Marked it. Thanks once again :)

Answer (score 1):

`GETDATE()` will always give you the current date this is the reason why the data is shown automatically from yesterday to today instead try something like below

```
DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, CONVERT(datetime, @ReportDate) - 1), 0) + '06:00'
AND
DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, CONVERT(datetime, @ReportDate)), 0) + '06:00'
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing out. replaced the getDate() and it works now.